# I want a to compare a variable with files in a directory and output the equals

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, compare

I am making a bash script where I want to find files that are equal to a variable. The equals will then be used.

I want to use "mogrify" to shrink a couple of image files that have the same name as the ones i gather from a list (similar to "dpkg -l"). It is not "dpkg -l" I am using but it is similar. My problem is that it prints all the files not just the equals. I am pretty sure this could be done with awk instead of a for-loop but I do not know how.

```
prog="`dpkg -l | awk '{print $1}'`"

for file in $dirone* $dirtwo*
do
     if [ "basename ${file}" = "${prog}" ]; then
         echo ${file} are equal
     else
         echo ${file} are not equal
     fi
done
```

Could you please help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there's a small typo. `if [ "basename ${file}" =...` should have backticks inside the double quotes, just like the `prog=...` line at the top does.

Second, if `$prog` is a multi-line string (like `dpkg -l`) you can't really compare a filename to the entire list. Instead you have to compare one item at a time to the filename.

Here's an example using `dpkg` and `/usr/bin`

```
#!/bin/bash
progs="`dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'`"

for file in /usr/bin/*
do
    base=`basename ${file}`

    for prog in ${progs}
    do
        if [ "${base}" = "${prog}" ]; then
            echo "${file}" matches "${prog}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i am after.. but i didn't get it to work. I am checking if i misspelled something.

Comment: Usual caveats apply re spaces in filenames but, other than that, this looks good.

Comment: I got it! the basename did show the ".png" which the "dpkg -l" didn't have. So when i added that it works!

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

The condition `"$file = $prog"` is a *single* string. You should try `"$file" = "$prog"` instead.

The following transcript shows the fix:

```
pax> ls -1 qq*
qq
qq.c
qq.cpp

pax> export xx=qq.cpp

pax> for file in qq* ; do
         if [[ "${file} = ${xx}" ]] ; then
             echo .....${file} equal
         else
             echo .....${file} not equal
         fi
     done
.....qq equal
.....qq.c equal
.....qq.cpp equal

pax> for file in qq* ; do
         if [[ "${file}" = "${xx}" ]] ; then
             echo .....${file} equal
         else
             echo .....${file} not equal
         fi
     done
.....qq not equal
.....qq.c not equal
.....qq.cpp equal
```

You can see in the last bit of output that only `qq.cpp` is shown as equal since it's the only one that matches `${xx}`.

The reason you're getting true is because that's what non-empty strings will give you:

```
pax> if [[ "" ]] ; then
         echo .....equal
     fi

pax> if [[ "x" ]] ; then
         echo .....equal
     fi
.....equal
```

That's because that form is the string length checking variation. From the `bash` manpage under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`:

> `string`
>   `-n string`
>             `True if the length of string is non-zero.`

---

*Update:*

The new code in your question won't quite work as expected. You need:

```
if [[ "$(basename ${file})" = "${prog}" ]]; then
```

to actually *execute* `basename` and use its output as the first part of the equality check.

Comment: Thanks but i am not using #C just bash and that is a bit over my comprehension. I tried using "$file" = "$prog" instead but it will just give me "no files where equal". I just realise that $file will give me both path and program name but the $prog will only give me the name of the program.

Comment: @AlMehdi, there's no C/C++/C# there, that just happens to be the files in that directory that I used for testing. The solution is pure `bash`. The problem you had was that the equality statement was actually a string-size statement. Your _new_ problem can be fixed with `basename`, which will give you the file part of a full file spec.

Comment: I see.. looked a lot more complicated. I was fooled by the ".c" and ".cpp". But i see now and i have tried it. Now i have "if [ "basename ${file} = ${prog}" ];". But it still don't give me equals.

Comment: ahh.. it might be $prog that is wrong. It puts the program names after each other separated with a space. i.e. "gimp deluge xournal".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `case/esac`

```
case "$file" in
  "$prog" ) echo "same";;
esac
```